# Give Name in DocuSign Email Body restAPI -JSON

Tags: json, docusignapi

I tried to JSON request for an Envelope for Signing Ceremony. But im getting name in Parenthesis on Email Body. I used name in Parenthesis while sending the JSON request, because in FullName Tag should included in Paranthesis(ex: (FirstName LastName) in DocuSign Singing Document, So im sending that request in that manner. But in Email Body Name i need name without Paranthesis. Any suggestions for that?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value in `FullName` comes from the name passed in the `signer` details, so if you are passing value with `Parenthesis` then same will come on an email and `FullName` tag.

There are two solutions to your problem:

- Either modify the `underlining document`, the document must contain
  the `Parenthesis` and you should place the FullName tag between the
  Parenthesis.
- Or to add two `Text tags` before and after the `FullName` tag. Each `Text`
  `Tags` will have a `Parenthesis (Left/Right)`